# Check a list against user input?

Tags: c#, list, input

I am trying to check whether a `list` contains a value, which is user input. The user input is in `textbox` named `txtId` and it is an `int`. If the `userId` is already existing in the `list` it has to throw an exception from my class `AlreadyExistingIdException`.

When I do it that way I get an error saying that `Contains()` has some invalid arguments:

```
 private void btnAddClass_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        Classes newClass;
         // Open new form to input  data
            AddNewClass add_form = new AddNewClass();
            if (add_form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                newClass = new Classes();
                // Get new  data from second form
                newClass = add_form.ExtractData();
               //check if id already exists in the list
                **if (l.fitnessClasses.Contains(newClass.Id))
                {
                    //throw an exception
                }
                else
                {**
                    // Add the new class to  file
                    l.AddClass(newClass);
                    lstClasses.Items.Clear();
                    //sort the list by ID
                    l.fitnessClasses.Sort((a, b) => a.Id.CompareTo(b.Id));

                    foreach (Classes cl in l.fitnessClasses)
                    {
                        lstClasses.Items.Add(cl);  //add  to list box
                    }


                    // Display new  
                    MessageBox.Show(newClass.Display());
                }
            }     
    }
```

Comment: add definitions of Classes etc.

Comment: You are using the variable l.  What is this defined as?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with linq you can do something like

```
if ( l.fitnessClasses.Any(x=> x.Id == newClass.ID)) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in the `Classes` (because your class needs to know how to compare instances, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for how to) then you can call:

```
l.fitnessClasses.Contains(newClass);
```

or use **[Linq](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list-contains)**

```
l.fitnessClasses.Contains(p=> p.Id == newClass.Id)
```